# Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet returns Empty when the validation is successful

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I use the Azure Powershell cmdlet below to validate both the ARM template json and ARM template params json files.

```
$result = Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName TestRG -TemplateFile TestARMTemplate.json -ApiVersion TestARMParams.json
```

I expect the cmdlet to return **true** (boolean type) if both input arguments are valid.

However, the result is empty.

The documentation is also not clear on the expected response of this cmdlet.

I would like to know whether the response I got is an expected response or not.

Note: I am using **Azure PowerShell version 1.5 (June 2016)** on Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source code for this Cmdlet [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/18be44918d9f4cfda0d260662ecbdce4b83999d4/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.ResourceManager/Cmdlets/Implementation/ResourceGroupDeployments/TestAzureResourceGroupDeploymentCmdlet.cs), I don't think it returns true or false. It actually returns an object of type [`List<PSResourceManagerError>`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/49fb96fe46ce8b759d4ff4b4fa1b39e134514f39/src/ResourceManager/Resources/Commands.ResourceManager/Cmdlets/SdkClient/ResourceManagerSdkClient.cs#L810). If you do a count on the `$result` object, it should return you zero if everything's ok.

Comment: Thanks very much, exactly what I need

Comment: Not sure if this is new, but today there's no need to look at the source code, the return value is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/test-azurermresourcegroupdeployment?view=azurermps-6.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a handy function for creating an `AggregateException` containing all the error information from a `PSResourceManagerError`

```
function New-DeploymentResultException([Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceManagerError]$error)
{
    $errorMessage = "$($error.Message) ($($error.Code)) [Target: $($error.Target)]"

    if ($error.Details)
    {
        $innerExceptions =  $error.Details | ForEach-Object { New-DeploymentResultException $_ }
        return New-Object System.AggregateException $errorMessage, $innerExceptions
    }
    else 
    { 
        return New-Object System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException $errorMessage
    }
}
```